# Mass Export From Excel Into SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Testing the connection error.

```
SQL.ActiveConnection = Cn
 FROM (OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data    Source=C:\Path\To\File.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES', Sheet1$)) wb
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you find such a syntax? Also, what parameter are you binding value to?

Comment: please see the revised code. The parameter that I am binding to is Column "Value1" in an excel sheet.  I am trying to import changes in the Excel sheet to its corresponding field in SQL.

Comment: You cannot bind identifiers like column or table names, only data values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSIS, it would be better and quicker to go that route. Doing it this way will mean that it is no longer an export process; it will be an import will all tasks being performed on the SQL Server and in SSIS.

Comment: If the import needs to be done on a regular basis, this is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I cannot use SSIS for this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an SQL Server distributed query with [OPENROWSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.105).aspx) to Excel workbook. Below assumes you have such permission to run MSSQL command and your Excel file has headers:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbSomething].[dbo].[tbl_Test] ([MyFieldValue]) 
SELECT wb.ColumnName 
FROM (OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Data Source=C:\Path\To\File.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES', Sheet1$)) wb
```

Alternatively for older workbook types:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbSomething].[dbo].[tbl_Test] ([MyFieldValue]) 
SELECT wb.ColumnName 
FROM (OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Data Source=C:\Path\To\File.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES', Sheet1$)) wb
```

To run this action query, place entire SQL in a VBA string and execute off the connection. There is no need for parameterization and hence the ADO command object.

```vb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO ... wb"

Cn.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: If the import is a one-off event, this is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, Parafait.  I tried it but it is not working. I have displayed the rewritten code with your suggestions in mind.

Comment: Hi Parafait, please see the revised code.  It has your suggestions in mind.

Comment: Parfait, the code does not work.  Can you please test a version and post it so that I can change the fields?  Please be aware that I am using a click event to trigger the code and hence the file is an Excel xlsm.